# How to split a string from xml in JAVA

Tags: java

I got the following xml output:

```
<PHOTO>
  <PHOTOURL URL="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>
</PHOTO>
```

I need to get the url of the image out of the string in JAVA.

Comment: <PHOTO>
  <PHOTOURL URL="http://stackoverflow.com/"/>
</PHOTO>

Comment: Use [edit] option to correct/add more information to your question. Don't use comment for that.

Comment: To add formatting (and ensure proper display) of code example simply select it and use `Code Sample` option from editors menu (`{}` icon).